# How do I change the color of the regression lines in ggPlot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I made a visualization of a regression. Currently this is what the graph looks like.
[image]

The regression lines are hard to see since they are the same color as the scatter plot dots.

My question is, how do I make the regression lines a different color from the scatter plot dots?

Here is my code:

```
(ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(x='score', y='relent', 
                                 color='factor(threshold)'))+
       geom_point()+
 scale_color_manual(values=['darkorange', 'purple'])+
 geom_smooth(method='lm',
             formula = 'y ~ x+I(x**2)',se=False, )+
 geom_vline(xintercept = 766, color = "red", size = 1, linetype = "dashed")+
 labs(y = "Yield",
       x = "Score")+
 theme_bw()
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to "duplicate" your `threshold` column with different values, e.g. in the code below I map 0 on 2 and 1 on 3. This duplicated column could then be mapped on the `color` aes inside `geom_smooth` and allows to set different colors for the regression lines.

My code below uses `R` or `ggplot2` but TBMK the code could be easily adapted to `plotnine`:

```r
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(
  relent = c(runif(n, 100, 200), runif(n, 150, 250)),
  score = c(runif(n, 764, 766), runif(n, 766, 768)),
  threshold = c(rep(0, n), rep(1, n))
)
df$threshold_sm <- c(rep(2, n), rep(3, n))

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = score, y = relent, color = factor(threshold))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkorange", "purple", "blue", "green")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 766, color = "red", size = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  labs(
    y = "Yield",
    x = "Score"
  ) +
  theme_bw()

p +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = factor(threshold_sm)),
    method = "lm",
    formula = y ~ x + I(x**2), se = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

A second option would be to add some transparency to the points so that the lines stand out more clearly and by the way deals with the overplotting of the points:

```r
p +
  geom_point(alpha = .3) +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = factor(threshold)),
              method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ x + I(x**2), se = FALSE
  ) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know how to plot the regression over the original. So I ended up just changing transparency since it also fixes the over plotting issue

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Petal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(group = Species))
```

[image]

With:

```
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Petal.Length, Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(group = Species))
```

[image]

When `aes(color = ...)` is specified inside of `ggplot()`, it is applied to both of the subsequent geoms. Moving it to `geom_point()` applies it to the points only.